# DNS_ANY working but DNS_TXT not working for DS_GET_RECORD php function

Tags: php, dns-get-record

I am trying to debug dns_get_record since it isn't working for me as expected.

I created a Text DNS record "laramon_59939919ec899.glibix.com." with value "dd678f947384ed8d3531465439ff852e01e6eb1d"

With:

```
$result=dns_get_record('laramon_59939919ec899.glibix.com.',DNS_TXT);
print_r($result);
```

I get:

```
Array
(
)
```

But with:

```
$result=dns_get_record('laramon_59939919ec899.glibix.com.',DNS_ANY);
print_r($result);
```

I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [host] => laramon_59939919ec899.glibix.com
            [class] => IN
            [ttl] => 86182
            [type] => TXT
            [txt] => dd678f947384ed8d3531465439ff852e01e6eb1d
            [entries] => Array
                (
                    [0] => dd678f947384ed8d3531465439ff852e01e6eb1d
                )

        )

)
```

The record I have added is of TXT type. Can someone help me understand why do I not get the correct record when I am specifically looking for TXT record?

Comment: You may have a DNS caching issue on your end. When I run your code with `DNS_TXT`, it provides the desired output.

Comment: Is there any way I can flush this cache, or force PHP not to use the cached value? I host with Linode

Comment: Not that I know of, because it just uses the host's DNS settings, and you can't tell the upstream DNS server not to returned cached results. The documentation for this function on PHP's page has some comments that recommend external utilities if you want to have more control over how you handle DNS calls.

Comment: @NickCoons I noticed that somehow DNS_ALL is not probably getting cached. So I rewrote my code to use DNS_ALL. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @NickCoons

The DNS record was being returned from cache. I fixed it by changing **DNS_TXT** to **DNS_ALL**. Somehow, it seems like only DNS_TXT is returning the cached result.